# Is there a way to show Reaction instead of Equation when referring to an equation?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, chemistry

I'm writing a thesis in which I have both equations and chemical reactions.

I was wondering if it can be changed something in equations referencing, so that when you refer to one of them that is a reaction there is written *Reaction 1.1* instead of *Equation 1.1*.

Is that possible, or do I have to use a different package for it?

I have seen that on some guides they suggest `chemfig` but none show how to enumerate it.

Comment: You might want to post some code. What exactly is used to have it print Equation 1.1

Comment: by default `\ref{..}` just makes `1.1` so you would write `Reaction \ref{myref}` instead of `Equation \ref{myref}` If you are using a package provided command that produces other text you should say what code you are using.

Answer (score 5):

Your objective may be achieved by loading and using the `cleveref` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % just for this example
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{reaction}{reaction}{reactions}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label[reaction]{eq:triv} % note the optional argument
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

A cross-reference to \cref{eq:triv}, and another one to \cref{eq:pyth}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't knwo why but it print both Reaction Equation 1.4... these are the packages i'm using \documentclass{uicthesi}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{Reaction}{Reaction}{Reactions}                                                                                              \begin{equation}
O_2 + 4e^- + 4H^+ \rightarrow 2H_2O
\label[Reaction]{Cathode1}
\end{equation}

Comment: Some comments: (i) Don't load `graphicx` twice. (ii) Don't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`; choose one or the other, but not both. (iii) Most importantly: where might one obtain the `uicthesi` document class from?

Comment: @lorenzoD'angelo - I found a copy of `uicthesi.cls` on web. Please add the following instructions to your preamble to make the unwanted string `Equation` go away: `\makeatletter \renewcommand\p@equation{} \makeatother`.

Comment: Done! It works perfectly!! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @lorenzoD'angelo - Glad it worked. Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With an bleeding edge `chemmacros` the following is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}[2016/05/04]
\chemsetup{ modules = {reactions} }

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % just for this example
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction} 
  2 H2 + O2 <=>> 2 H2O "\label{rct:water}"
\end{reaction}

\begin{equation}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2  \label{eq:pyth}
\end{equation}

A cross-reference to \cref{rct:water}, and another one to \cref{eq:pyth}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Of course this is different from Mico's answer since reactions and equations are numbered independently here.

Comment: That looks great for chemistry. Just curious: why are labels double-quoted label?

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki per default `chemmacros`' reactions are parsed by the `chemformula` package. In order to prevent the parsing of the label as chemical formula I escaped the input with `"…"`.